# Ansible: insert a single word on an existing line in a file

Tags: ansible, sshd

I have to use Ansible modules in order to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file - every time I create a new user I want to append it at these two lines:

```
AllowUsers root osadmin <new_user>
AllowGroups root staff <new_group>
```

At this moment I'm using the shell module to execute a sed command but would like to use lineinfile, if possible

```
- shell: "sed -i '/^Allow/ s/$/ {{ user_name }}/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Using `sed -i` in such files is dangerous. At least, use `-i.bak` to have a backup just in case.

Comment: I don't want to use sed, I'd like to replace it if possible with lineinfile module

Comment: lineinfile is often an antipattern- in this case, you probably want to bring the sshd_config file inside configuration management anyhow.

Comment: tedder42 seems especially opinionated on this issue as I've seen him make the same comment on other posts about usage of `lineinfile`. Really it's a matter of suitability for your situation. Don't hesitate to use lineinfile if it serves your purpose. It may not makes sense to manage all of `sshd_config` in a template.

Comment: Just a note, you can have AllowUsers multiple times in sshd, you don't need to put all the users in the same line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it in a single play with a newline, but I think it's cleaner to use two `lineinfile` plays for this.

```
- hosts: '127.0.0.1'
  vars:
    usernames:
       - larry
       - curly
       - moe
    usergroups:
       - stooges
       - admins
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^AllowUsers'
        line: "AllowUsers {{usernames | join(' ')}}"
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^AllowGroups'
        line: "AllowGroups {{usergroups | join(' ')}}"
```

Note that `groups` is a reserved word so don't use that as a variable name.

Comment: It would be more robust to add `insertafter: '^AllowUsers.+$'`, as that will create the AllowUsers line at the end of the file if the regex isn't found. If it is found, it will replace the line.

Answer (score 26):

The [replace module](http://docs.ansible.com/replace_module.html) will replace all instances of a regular expression pattern within a file. Write a task to match the `AllowUsers` line and replace it with the original line appended with the user name. To ensure the task is idempotent, a negative lookahead assertion in the regular expression checks if the user name already appears in the line. For example:

```
- name: Add user to AllowUsers
  replace:
    backup: yes
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^(AllowUsers(?!.*\b{{ user_name }}\b).*)$'
    replace: '\1 {{ user_name }}'
```

Comment: The regex in this answer works just as well for `lineinfile` too if you use `backrefs: yes`. I was struggling with this until I found this regex - turns out the secret sauce I was missing was the `\b`.

Comment: can anyone please clarify what is `\1` or where can i read about it?

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer assumes that the complete list of users is available at runtime, while the most popular answer can fail when there is a dash in the username, because `\b` interprets it as a word boundary. The following solution assumes that the playbook cannot regenerate the complete list of usernames from scratch, and tries and handle the corner case of dashes:

```
name: add a user to the list of AllowUsers if not present
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  backrefs: yes
  backup: yes
  regexp: "^AllowUsers((?:(?:\s+\S+(?!\S))(?<!\s{{ username }}))+\s*?)(\n?)$"
  line: "AllowUsers\1 {{ username }}\2"
  validate: /usr/sbin/sshd -t -f %s
```

As a bonus, I threw in sshd_config backup and verification.

How the (interesting part of the) regular expression works:

```
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
(                         |
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
  (?:                     | This group is not captured
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
    (?:\s+\S+(?!\S))      | Matches any sequence of whitespace characters fol-
                          | lowed by any sequence of non-whitespace characters,
                          | that is to say a leading space and a username. The
                          | negative look-ahead at the end prevents a "catast-
                          | rophic backtracking". Also, this group is not cap-
                          | tured.
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
    (?<!\s{{ username }}) | Applies a negative look-behind on the username, so
                          | that if the username found by the previous expres-
                          | sion matches, the regular expression fails. The
                          | match on a leading whitespace character ensures
                          | that the comparison is made on the complete string.
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
  )+                      | Groups the detection of a username and its negative
                          | look-behind together. The "+" quantifier is used
                          | here on the assumption that the file already cont-
                          | ains at least one username, but "*" could be used
                          | for a more relaxed matching.
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
  \s*?                    | Matches any trailing whitespace. The match is lazy
                          | in order to detect the newline character later on.
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
)                         | Captures the whole text after "AllowUsers" (this
                          | will be \1).
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
(\n?)                     | Captures either a newline character or an empty
                          | string (this will be \2).
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
```

If the regular expression matches, it means that the line exists and that it does not contain `{{ username }}`, so we append it.

If the regular expression does not match, it means that either the line does not exist or that it contains `{{ username }}`, and we do nothing.

Comment: yamllint hates the first \s in (?:\s+\S+(?!\S))

Comment: @Electrawn I'm sorry, I don't know why it does that. It could be because validating regular expressions (especially such a convoluted one) is hard, or because I'm using double quotes and I should not? I don't have access to my setup anymore, so I can't test easily.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I needed add user to sudoers group, let's say 'testuser' to line:

```
User_Alias SOMEADMIN = smoeuser1, someuser2, someuser3
```

This worked well for me:

```
- name: add testuser to end of line
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/sudoers.d/somegroup
        state: present
        regexp: '^(User_Alias(.*)$)'
        backrefs: yes
        line: '\1, testuser'
```

The point is that if I had *'^User_Alias(.*.)$'* in regexp and not *'^(User_Alias(.*.)$)'* it didn't work and whole line was replaced. With *()* arround searched text the result was OK:

```
User_Alias SOMEADMIN = smoeuser1, someuser2, someuser3, testuser
```

So then anything can work in *line:*, included ansible variables like `"{{ usernames | join(', ') }}"`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
 - name: Add Group to AllowGroups
   lineinfile: 
     dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
     backup=True
     backrefs=True
     state=present
     regexp='^(AllowGroups(?!.*\b{{ groupname }}\b).*)$'
     line='\1 {{ groupname }}'
```