# Ansible - Append variable in line

Tags: ansible

I want to append attribute to a file, instead of replacing or setting it on a new line.

Content of file:

```
PATH = "/a/path"
```

The variable which attributes has to append in the file:

```
"{{ key.values() | map(attribute='hi') | list | join(' ') }}"
```

The output of the variable is:

```
/hi1 /hi2 /hi3
```

Trying to append with `lineinfile`, but the parameter `insertafter` places the attributes on a new line, instead of the same line.

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /file
    state: present
    insertafter: 'PATH = "'
    line: "{{ mounts.values() | map(attribute='mountpoint') | list | join(' ') }}"
```

Expected result:

```
PATH = "/a/path /hi1 /h2 /hi3"
```

Actual result:

```
PATH = "/a/path"
/hi1 /hi2 /hi3
```

Receiving syntax errors if I use the method described here: [Ansible: insert a single word on an existing line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432367/ansible-insert-a-single-word-on-an-existing-line-in-a-file)

Which module should I use for this particular use case?

Using Ansible v2.1.2.0

---

### edit

The backrefs option gives the same result, which is not expected:

```
 - lineinfile:
     dest: /file
     backrefs: yes
     regexp: 'PATH = "'
     line: "{{ key.values() | map(attribute='hi') | list | join(' ') }}"
```

Comment: When you use backrefs your regex has to have capturing groups for it to work. See my example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for helping @Mir.
Final solution:

```
 - lineinfile:
    dest: /file
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '(^PATH\s+\=\s+)(?:")([\w+\s/]+)(?<!{{ hi }})(?:")'
    line: '\1"\2 {{ hi }}"'
```

Where `hi` is the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lineinfile module has the [backrefs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) option that goes in pair with the regexp option and allows you to match an existing line and change only parts of it.

Something like (not tested)

```
- lineinfile:
  [...]
  regexp: ^PATH = "(.*)"$
  line: PATH="\1 {{ your_variable_here}}"
  backrefs: yes
```

Is probably what you need.

Comment: Got the same result. Because "If the regexp does match, the last matching line will be replaced by the expanded line parameter." It replaces the whole line.

Comment: @Kevin it replaces the line, but you can use backreferences to keep in your line parts (or all) of the existing line, so it can be used to add parts to an existing string.